# Seeding my database for FoodApp API using Faker cant use both import and require in the same file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, faker

I am trying us use the Faker npm package to seed data into my new database so that I can properly test my filters. The issue is that I am unable to use both require and import in the same app. All of my other packages make sure of require while faker has to use import. I have come across a few suggested fixes that all don't seem to work.

What I've done so far is to include the below lines of code at he top of my server.js as well as have added type: module to my package.json.

I think the issue may have something to do with  how my routes are configured but I'm not 100% sure.

The error I am getting with this configuration is as below

```
node:internal/errors:465
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Users\darre\Desktop\Web Development\foodappbackend\routes\subscribers.js from C:\Users\darre\Desktop\Web Development\foodappbackend\server.js not supported.   
subscribers.js is treated as an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which declares all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename subscribers.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules, or change "type": "module" to "type": "commonjs" in C:\Users\darre\Desktop\Web Development\foodappbackend\package.json to treat all .js files as CommonJS (using .mjs for all ES modules instead).

    at file:///C:/Users/darre/Desktop/Web%20Development/foodappbackend/server.js:28:27
    at async Promise.all (index 0) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

ADDED CODE AT TOP OF SERVER.JS

```
import {createRequire} from "module";
const require = createRequire(
    import.meta.url
);
```

PACKAGE.JSON

```
{

  "name": "foodappbackend",

  "version": "1.0.0",

  "description": "",

  "type": "module",

  "main": "app.js",

  "scripts": {


    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"

  },

  "author": "",

  "license": "ISC",

  "dependencies": {


    "@faker-js/faker": "^7.2.0",


    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",


    "body-parser": "^1.20.0",


    "cors": "^2.8.5",


    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",


    "express": "^4.18.1",


    "express-session": "^1.17.3",


    "mongoose": "^6.3.3",


    "passport": "^0.5.3",


    "passport-facebook": "^3.0.0",


    "passport-google-oauth20": "^2.0.0",


    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",


    "passport-local-mongoose": "^7.1.0"

  }
}
```

SERVER.JS

```
import {createRequire} from "module";
const require = createRequire(
    import.meta.url
);

require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors")



mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL)



const db = mongoose.connection



db.on("error", () => console.error(error))
db.once("open", () => console.log("connected to database"))

app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())

const subscribersRouter = require("./routes/subscribers")
const restaurantsRouter = require("./routes/restaurants")
const ordersRouter = require("./routes/orders")


app.use("/subscribers", subscribersRouter)
app.use("/restaurants", restaurantsRouter)
app.use("/orders", ordersRouter)





app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server has started on port 3000")
});
```

RESTUARANTS.js

```
const express = require("express")
const router = express.Router()
const Restaurant = require("../models/restaurant")





// router.get("/test", (req, res) => {

//     const randomName = faker.name.firstName()

//     console.log(randomName)

// })



// FILTER OPTIONS
router.get("/filter", async (req, res) => {

    //USERS CHOSEN CATEGORIES SENT THROUGH THE REQUEST
    const chosenCats = await req.body.categories

    var spendPerHead = await req.body.spendperhead

    const numberOfHeads = await req.body.numberofheads

    if (spendPerHead != null && spendPerHead.length === 1){
        const duplicateItems = (arr, numberOfRepetitions) =>
            arr.flatMap(i => Array.from({
                length: numberOfRepetitions
            }).fill(i));

       spendPerHead = duplicateItems(spendPerHead, numberOfHeads);
    }else{
        console.log("no SPH duplication needed")
    }

    console.log(spendPerHead)
   

    // RETURNS ONLY RESTURANT OPTIONS WITH CATEGORIES CONTAINING AT LEAST ONE OPTION IN THE USERS REQUESTED CATEGORIES
    let foundMatch = await Restaurant.aggregate(
        [{
            $match: {
                categories: {
                    $in: chosenCats
                }
            }
        }]
    )

   
//RESULT OF ALL MENUE ITEMS MATCHING USER CATEGORIES
    let result = []

//FULL RESULT OF BOTH RESTURANTS MATCHING USERS CHOSEN CATEGORIES AND MENUE ITEMS OF THOSE RESTURANTS MATCHING USERS CATEGORIES    
    let fullResult = []

    // LOOPS THROUGH ALL RESTURANT OPTIONS MENUES AND OUTPUTS MENUE ITEMS MATCHING THE USERS CHOSEN CATEGORIES
    for (let i = 0; i < foundMatch.length; i++) {
        foundMatch[i].menue.filter(function checkOptions(option) {
            for (let x = 0; x < option.categories.length; x++) {
                if (option.categories[x] === chosenCats[0] || option.categories[x] === chosenCats[1] || option.categories[x] === chosenCats[2] || option.categories[x] === chosenCats[3] || option.categories[x] === chosenCats[4] || option.categories[x] === chosenCats[5] || option.categories[x] === chosenCats[6]) {

                    // FILTERS RESULTS BASED ON TOTAL SPEND PER HEAD CHOSEN BY USER
                    if (option.price <= spendPerHead[1]) {
                        result.push(option)
                    }else if (spendPerHead === undefined){
                        result.push(option)
                    }


                }
            }
        })
    }




    

    //PUSHES BOTH RESTURANT FILTER RESULT AND MENUE ITEM OPTION FILTER RESULT INTO A SINGLE ARRAY TO BE SENT AS A JSON RESPONSE BY THE SERVER

     
    fullResult.push(result)
    fullResult.push(foundMatch)
// console.log(result)
    try {
        // position 0 == menue option result position 1 == resturant options result
        res.json(fullResult)
    } catch (err) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).json({
                message: err.message
            })

        }
    }


})

// Getting All
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const restaurants = await Restaurant.find()
        res.json(restaurants)
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({
            message: err.message
        })
    }
})

// Getting One
router.get("/:id", getRestaurant, (req, res) => {
    res.json(res.restaurant)
})

// Creating One
router.post("/createrestaurant", async (req, res) => {
    const restaurant = new Restaurant({
        src: req.body.src,
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
        menue: req.body.menue,
        rating: req.body.rating,
        categories: req.body.categories
    })
    try {
        const newRestaurant = await restaurant.save()
        res.status(201).json(newRestaurant)
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json({
            message: err.message
        })
    }
})

// Updating One 
router.patch("/:id", getRestaurant, async (req, res) => {
    if (req.body.name != null) {
        res.restaurant.name = req.body.name
    }
    if (req.body.title != null) {
        res.restaurant.title = req.body.title
    }
    if (req.body.description != null) {
        res.restaurant.description = req.body.description
    }
    if (req.body.menue != null) {
     const currentMenue = res.restaurant.menue
     const newMenueItem =  req.body.menue

     currentMenue.push(newMenueItem)

         
    }
    try {
        const updatedRestaurant = await res.restaurant.save()
        res.json(updatedRestaurant)
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json({
            message: err.message
        })
    }
})



// Deleting One
router.delete("/:id", getRestaurant, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await res.restaurant.remove()
        res.json({
            message: "Deleted Restaurant"
        })
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({
            message: err.message
        })
    }
})


async function getRestaurant(req, res, next) {

    let restaurant
    try {
        restaurant = await Restaurant.findById(req.params.id)
        if (restaurant == null) {
            return res.status(404).json({
                message: "cannot find Restaurant"
            })
        }
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).jsong({
            message: err.message
        })
    }
    res.restaurant = restaurant
    next()
}

module.exports = router
```

SUBSCRIBERS.JS

```
 const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const Subscriber = require("../models/subscriber");
const passport = require("passport");
const session = require("express-session");
const Order = require("../models/order");
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const facebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;






router.use(session({
    secret: "foodsecrets",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

router.use(passport.initialize());
router.use(passport.session());
passport.use(Subscriber.createStrategy());


passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    Subscriber.findById(id, function (err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});






// Google auth routes    
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: "330178790432-ro0cr35k37f7kq4ln4pdq6dqdpqqtri6.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        clientSecret: "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",
        callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/subscribers/google/callback",
    },
    function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, email, done) {
        //check user table for anyone with a facebook ID of profile.id

        const ID = JSON.stringify(email.id)

        console.log(ID)
        Subscriber.findOne({
            googleID: ID
        }, function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            //No user was found... so create a new user with values from Facebook (all the profile. stuff)
            if (!user) {
                const subscriber = new Subscriber({
                    googleID: ID,
                    username: email.displayName,
                    email: email.emails[0].value,
                    provider: 'google',
                    //now in the future searching on User.findOne({'facebook.id': profile.id } will match because of this next line
                    google: profile._json
                });
                subscriber.save(function (err) {
                    if (err) console.log(err);
                    return done(err, user);
                });
            } else {
                //found user. Return
                return done(err, user);
            }
        });
    }));

router.get("/google",


    passport.authenticate("google", {
        scope: ["profile", "email"]
    })

);

router.get("/google/callback",



    passport.authenticate("google", {
        successRedirect: "https://www.youtube.com/",
        failureRedirect: "/login/failed",

    })


);


// Facebook Auth Routes

passport.use(new facebookStrategy({
        clientID: "1142565916475628",
        clientSecret: "f0c297bf99f71d090b317cdcaa5ae6d8",
        callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/subscribers/facebook/callback",
        profileFields: ["email", "displayName", "name"]
    },
    function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        //check user table for anyone with a facebook ID of profile.id
        console.log(profile)


        const ID = JSON.stringify(profile.id)

        console.log(ID)
        Subscriber.findOne({
            facebookID: ID
        }, function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            //No user was found... so create a new user with values from Facebook (all the profile. stuff)
            if (!user) {
                const subscriber = new Subscriber({
                    facebookID: ID,
                    username: profile.displayName,
                    email: profile._json.email,
                    provider: profile.provider,
                    //now in the future searching on User.findOne({'facebook.id': profile.id } will match because of this next line
                    facebook: profile._json
                });
                subscriber.save(function (err) {
                    if (err) console.log(err);
                    return done(err, user);
                });
            } else {
                //found user. Return
                return done(err, user);
            }
        });
    }
));

router.get("/facebook",
    passport.authenticate("facebook", {
        scope: [ "email"]
    })

);

router.get("/facebook/callback",
    passport.authenticate("facebook", {
        successRedirect: "https://www.youtube.com/",
        failureRedirect: "/login/failed",

    })
);


// Edit cart (user must be authenticated)
router.patch("/editcart", async (req, res) => {

    // DETERMINES IF USER IS AUTH AND IF ADD OR REMOVE ITEM MAKE SURE ADD OR REMOVE PROP IS OUTSIDE OF CART ITEM OBECT
    if (req.isAuthenticated() && req.body.addOrRemoveItem === "add") {
        var sub
        // FINDS SUBSCRIBER BASED ON REQUEST
        sub = await Subscriber.findById(req.user._id, function (err, docs) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                console.log("founduser1")
            }
        }).clone()
        console.log(sub.cart)

        // PUSHES ITEM FROM REQUEST INTO SUBSCRIBERS CART
        const currentCart = sub.cart
        const newCartItem = req.body.cartItem
        await currentCart.push(newCartItem)

        //    DETERMINES IF USER IS AUTH AND IF ADD OR REMOVE ITEM MAKE SURE REMOVE ITEM PROP IS NOT IN CARTITEM OBJECT
    } else if (req.isAuthenticated() && req.body.addOrRemoveItem === "remove") {
        var sub
        sub = await Subscriber.findById(req.user._id, function (err, docs) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                console.log("founduser")
            }
        }).clone()

        // REMOVES A CART ITEM BASED ON ITEM ID MUST PASS IN CART ITEM ID ONLY REMOVES OFF OF SPCIFIC ITEM ID
        const cartItemId = req.body.id
        await Subscriber.updateOne({
            _id: sub._id
        }, {
            $pull: {
                cart: {
                    _id: cartItemId
                }
            }
        })
    } else {
        console.log("not reading")
    }
    try {
        // SAVES THE CHANGES IN THE SUBSCRIBERS COLLECTION
        const updatedSubscriber = await sub.save()
        res.json(updatedSubscriber)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }

})


// Create Order (user must be authenticated)
router.post("/createorder", async (req, res) => {

    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {

        try {
            // FINDS SUBSCRIBER BASED ON REQUEST ID
            const sub = await Subscriber.findById(req.user._id, function (err, docs) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                } else {
                    console.log("founduser")
                }
            }).clone()

            //STORES/TARGETS THE PENDING ORDER OF SUBSCRIBER
            const pendingOrder = await sub.pendingOrder

            //DETERMINES IF THE USER ALREADY HAS A PENDING ORDER, IF USER HAS PENDING ORDERS THEY WILL BE BLOCKED FROM CREATING A NEW ORDER UNTIL THE PREVIOUS ORDER IS CONFIRMED OR CANCELLED
            
                // IDENTIFIES SPECIFIC CART BASED ON REQUEST
                const cart = req.user.cart

                // STORES/TARGETS THE CART OF THE SUBSCRIBER
                const subCart = sub.cart

                //MAPS THE PRICE OF EACH CART ITEM TO AN ARRAY
                const itemTotals = cart.map(prop => prop.price)

                //FUNCTION FOR SUMMING ALL VALUES IN AN ARRAY
                const reducer = (accumulator, curr) => accumulator + curr;

                //USES REDUCER FUNCTION TO SUM ALL PRICES OF ITEMS IN CART
                const total = itemTotals.reduce(reducer)

                //CREATES A NEW ORDER USING THE ABOVE STORED VARIABLES
                const order = new Order({
                    userID: req.user._id,
                    total: total,
                    items: cart,
                    confirmed: false
                })

                // PUSHES NEW PENDING ORER INTO SUBSCRIBERS PENDING ORDER ARRAY
                await pendingOrder.push(order)



                //EMPTIES THE SUBSCRIBERS CART
                await subCart.splice(0, subCart.length);

                // SAVES THE NEW ORDER TO THE MAIN ORDERS COLLECTION  & THE SUBS PENDING ORDER          
                const newOrder = await order.save()
                const newPendingOrder = await sub.save()


                //SENDS BACK BOTH THE ORDERS COLLECTION AND USERS ORDER HISTORY ARRAY
                res.status(201).send({
                    newOrder,
                    newPendingOrder

                })
             
        } catch (err) {
            res.status(400).json({
                message: err.message
            })
        }
    }
})

// GET ONE SUBSCRIBER BASED ON REQUEST ID USING PASSPORT IDEALLY USED FOR DATA NEEDED FOR THE PAYMENT PAGE AFTER MAKING AN ORDER

router.get("/getone", async (req, res) =>{
    if (req.isAuthenticated()){
const sub = await Subscriber.findById(req.user._id, function (err, docs) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        console.log("founduser")
    }

}).clone()

try {
    res.json(sub)
} catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({
        message: err.message
    })
}

    }
})


// CONFIRMS ORDER ON POST REQUEST RESULTING FROM A PAYMENT CONFIRMATION ON THE FRONTEND
router.post("/confirmorder", async (req, res) => {
    if (req.isAuthenticated) {
        const sub = await Subscriber.findById(req.user._id, function (err, docs) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                console.log("founduser")
            }

        }).clone()

        const pendingOrder = await sub.pendingOrder
        const subOrderHistory = await sub.orderHistory

        const mainOrder = await Order.findById(pendingOrder[0]._id, function (err, docs) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                console.log("Found Order")
            }
        }).clone()
        console.log(mainOrder)


        await subOrderHistory.push(pendingOrder[0]);

    
        mainOrder.confirmed = true

        try {
            pendingOrder.splice(0, pendingOrder.length);
            const updatedOrder = await mainOrder.save()
            const updatedSub = await sub.save()
            res.status(201).send({
                updatedOrder,
                updatedSub

            })

        } catch (err) {
            res.status(400).json({
                message: err.message
            })
        }


    }



})


// GETS ALL SUBSCRIBERS
router.get("/getall", async (req, res) => {

    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        try {
            const subscribers = await Subscriber.find()
            res.json(subscribers)
        } catch (err) {
            res.status(500).json({
                message: err.message
            })
        }

    }

});

// DELIVERS ALL DATA NEEDED FOR LOGGED IN HOMEPAGE BASED ON IF THE USER IS AUTHENTICATED
router.get("/loggedin", async (req, res) => {

    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        try {

            const subscribers = await Subscriber.findById(req.user._id, function (err, docs) {

                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                } else {
                    console.log("Found User!")

                }
            }).clone()

            res.json(subscribers)

        } catch (err) {
            res.status(500).json({
                message: err.message
            })
        }

    }

});

// // Getting One
// router.get("/:id", getSubscriber, (req, res) => {
//     res.json(res.subscriber)
// });


// LOGIN USING PASSPORT JS 
router.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    const subscriber = new Subscriber({
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password,
        email: req.body.email
    });
    req.login(subscriber, async function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            try {
                passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function () {
                    console.log("Authenticated")
                    console.log(req)
                    res.status(201).json("authenticated")

                })
            } catch (err) {
                res.status(400).json({
                    message: err.message
                })
            }
        }
    })

})

// REGISTER USING PASSPORT JS
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
    Subscriber.register({
        username: req.body.username,
        email: req.body.email

    }, req.body.password, async (err, subscriber) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            try {
                await passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function () {

                    console.log("is authenticated")
                    res.status(201).json(newSubscriber)

                })
                const newSubscriber = await subscriber.save()

            } catch (err) {
                res.status(400).json({
                    message: err.message
                })
            }
        }
    });
})


// UPDATES ONE SUBSCRIBER BASED ON THE SUBSCRIBERS ID
router.patch("/:id", getSubscriber, async (req, res) => {
    if (req.body.email != null) {
        res.subscriber.email = req.body.email
    }
    if (req.body.password != null) {
        res.subscriber.password = req.body.password
    }
    try {
        const updatedSubscriber = await res.subscriber.save()
        res.json(updatedSubscriber)
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json({
            message: err.message
        })
    }
})

// DELETES ONE SUBSCRIBER BASED ON THE SUBSCRIBERS ID
router.delete("/:id", getSubscriber, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await res.subscriber.remove()
        res.json({
            message: "Deleted Subscriber"
        })
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({
            message: err.message
        })
    }
})

// FUNCTION FOR GETTING A SPECIFIC SUBSCRIBER FROM THE SUBSCRIBERS COLLECTION BASED ON A PRIOVIDED ID IN THE REQUEST PARAMATERS
async function getSubscriber(req, res, next) {
    let subscriber
    try {
        subscriber = await Subscriber.findById(req.params.id)
        if (subscriber == null) {
            return res.status(404).json({
                message: "cannot find subscriber"
            })
        }
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            message: err.message
        })
    }
    res.subscriber = subscriber
    next()
}

module.exports = router
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use faker with `require`:

```
// node v14.18.1
const {faker} = require('@faker-js/faker');

console.log(faker.datatype.uuid());
```

If you check the package you will see that inside dist folder it has both **esm** and **cjs** versions.

[image]